# c portability code with socket

Tags: c, portability

This is a part of my program:

```
  while((total_bytes_read != fsize) && ((nread = read(f_sockd, filebuffer, fsize_tmp)) > 0)){
    if(write(fd, filebuffer, nread) != nread){
      perror("write RETR");
      onexit(f_sockd, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    total_bytes_read += nread;
    fsize_tmp -= nread;
  }
```

where `total_bytes_read, fsize, nread` are declared as `uint32_t`.
On a 64 bit machine there's no problem, it compiles and run very well (this part of code has to receive a file).
The problem is when i compile on a 32bit machine because i got this error: 
`warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'ssize_t' (aka 'int') and 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wsign-compare] if(write(fd, filebuffer, nread) != nread){`
I don't know how to solve this problem because if i change `if(write(fd, filebuffer, nread) != nread){` **to** `if(nread != (uint32_t)write(fd, filebuffer, nread)){` the program **doesn't receive the file anymore** but it print *(part of)* the file content to stdout.
Why i got this strange behaviour and how can i solve this thing?

Comment: Also note that there are *two* different variants of 32bit — non-LFS and LFS (largefile), both having different type sizes. You simply can't use `uint32_t` because it will cause random failures, earlier of later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the right types. [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) says:

```
ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);
^^^^^^^                             ^^^^^^
```

So that's what you should use. Not `int`, not `uint64_t`, not `unsigned long long` etc.

Comment: oh thanks! i don't knew about this! i've always known that they was the same!!